# Gnuplot setting x axis value as lines from text

Tags: gnuplot

The title might be a little bit confusing , but I can't think of anything better.

I have a file that contains values, for example:

```
1 2 15
1 2 15
1 2 15
```

...and so on, and so on N times, where N is the number of lines in the file.
The problem is, then the values across the file are all the same (nothing changes), as in the aforementioned example, I get an error:

```
Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
```

and the plot consists of only dots in the middle of the picture. What I'd like to see in such a case is a series of lines, in this case on y = 1, 2, and 15.

So, how can I set gnuplot to use line num as x value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row number can be accessed as column 0:

```
set style data line
unse key
plot 'file.txt' using 0:1, '' using 0:2, '' using 0:3
```

This gives you three lines at y=1, y=2 and y=15

You can also iterate over the columns:

```
plot for [i=1:3] 'file.txt' using 0:i
```